# RxSwift throttle how to get only last value from stream

Tags: swift, uitextfield, rx-swift

I'm learning RxSwift, what I would like achieve is to get mechanism which prints me `text` from `UITextFied`, but after given interval.

How it works now: when I type first character this character is immediately printed out (not after delay how I expected) and if I keep on typing long sentence, `text` is printed after each two second (as interval is set in throttle), but I would like to have only latest `text` value.

My code:

```
inputField.rx.text.orEmpty
        .throttle(2, latest: true, scheduler: MainScheduler.instance)
        .subscribe(onNext: { text in
            print("\(text)")
        }, onDisposed: nil)
        .addDisposableTo(disposeBag)
```

Im looking for your help Rx fellows :) Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use `debounce` instead of `throttle`.

From the documentation for `debounce`:

> Ignores elements from an observable sequence which are followed by
>   another element within a specified relative time duration, using the
>   specified scheduler to run throttling timers.

From the documentation for `throttle`.

> Returns an Observable that emits the first and the latest item emitted
>   by the source Observable during sequential time windows of a specified
>   duration.